# rsyslog: discard multiple messages

Tags: rsyslog

How can I discard multiple messages at once using rsyslog?
This doesn't work and I'm unable to find a working example:

```
# Do not log any keepass and chmomium messages
if $programname == 'chromium.desktop'       then /dev/null
if $programname == 'keepass2.desktop'       then /dev/null

& stop
```

The solution below works, but shows an error when checking with `rsyslogd -N1 -f <config_file>`

```
rsyslogd: version 8.4.2, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.d/00-discard.conf
rsyslogd: CONFIG ERROR: there are no active actions configured. Inputs will run, but no output whatsoever is created. [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2103 ]
rsyslogd: run failed with error -2103 (see rsyslog.h or try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2103 to learn what that number means)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `& stop` means "repeat the previous selector", and do action "stop" which stops further processing of the selected message. So you would need to put it after each `if ...` selecting line.  However, since your action is to write to `/dev/null`,  you may as well make the first line do what you want, i.e.

```
if $programname == 'chromium.desktop'       then stop
if $programname == 'keepass2.desktop'       then stop
```

Comment: This works, but config check using `-N1 -f <config_file>` results in `rsyslogd: version 8.4.2, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.d/00-discard.conf
rsyslogd: CONFIG ERROR: there are no active actions configured. Inputs will run, but no output whatsoever is created. [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2103 ]
rsyslogd: run failed with error -2103 (see rsyslog.h or try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2103 to learn what that number means)`

Comment: I would have thought you should only get this error if you have no other logging rules, or if you test an included file independently of the main configuraton.

Comment: Well, that's what it is - an included file, only a part of the config, so everything is OK.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to discard messages described here: [Discarding unwanted messages](http://www.rsyslog.com/discarding-unwanted-messages/)

Instead of check the "msg" property as in the example, just check the "programname" property.

`:programname, contains, "chromium.desktop" ~`

`:programname, contains, "keepass2.desktop" ~`

Comment: but in this manner you cannot combine conditions, correct?